# Different Stat For Usage In Audit Report & Site GUI

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-usage, audit-log-reports

In SharePoint 2013 on-premises we have auditing turned on.  When I run a custom audit report I get a number of views for a particular document in the resulting excel report.

In the SharePoint GUI when I hover over that document there is a context menu that appears and on that flyout there it shows a different number for number of views for the same document.

How do I know which is the correct figure?